# images do not display in ionic 3

Tags: ionic3

I am working on ionic 3 project , data are fetched from my web service . all data apperas very well in my app(browser) except the images , it shows only the name of the images, but not the images themselves . i am using Blob as data type for image field in mysql .

Comment: How do You Displaying Images

Comment: Please share your code from templates how you display images, also how does your app "obtain" image data?